# Система не обнаружила .dll

Tags: windows, dll

[image]

Файл закинут в Windows\System32\ но все равно система его не находит, пробовал даже перезагружать комп... не помогает

Comment: Разрядность системы? Разрядность SolarSystem.exe? Разрядность GLAUX.DLL? Каким файловым менеджером закидывали?

Comment: Решено. Надо было кидать в SysWOW64

Comment: могли кинуть рядом самой программой, это первое место, где ищутся длл-ки